# Flutter: Is there any way to access Gmail (mail boxes) in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make an app to access emails from mail-boxes (such as Gmail and Yahoo Mail) and to store it in my local storage. Is there any way in a flutter to implement that.?

Answer (score 2):

Sure there is.

You could use [imap_client](https://pub.dev/packages/imap_client) or [enough_mail](https://pub.dev/packages/enough_mail) or others.

If you really *only* want *Google Mail*, you could use their own package [googleapis](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis)

Comment: I have tried imap_client but not getting access to emails. @nvoigt

Comment: You will need to actually ask a question with a specific problem statement then. Don't forget to include an [mcve].